# How to make a parent view controller that manages two sub view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I am working on adding some functionality to an app that is very similar to the app switching drawer on Springboard on iOS. I want to be able to have a button that I can hit that will animate the y-coordinates of the view up so that another view is exposed at the bottom. Like I said, very similar to the home button double-tap feature on iOS.

After doing some looking around, it appears that I need to wrap both of the sub view controllers into one parent view controller.

How can I go about doing this? The existing view controller is pretty complicated so I am having a hard time figuring out where to start.

Comment: If you already have the two sub VCs, you just make another VC that manages the placement of the subVCs' `view`s, and keeps strong references to the sub VCs as well. It should also be responsible for handling the interaction with the button. Does that help?

Comment: Yeah that helps. So what about the hierarchy then? Currently view C makes and pushes view D. Does this new container view become D and D contains E & F type thing?

Comment: yeah that's pretty much correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that you need to use a parent view controller to do this. This code worked for me to do what I think you want. I have one BOOL ivar to keep track of whether the bottom view has been revealed, and use the same button in the main view to toggle between the two states.

```
-(IBAction)slideInController:(UIButton *) sender {
    if (viewRevealed == NO) {
        next = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Blue"];
        next.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y + self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 100); // my NextController's view was made 100 points high in IB.
        [self.view.window addSubview:next.view];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.6 animations:^{
            self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y - 100);
            next.view.center = CGPointMake(next.view.center.x, next.view.center.y - 100);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            viewRevealed = YES;
        }];
    }else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.6 animations:^{
            self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y + 100);
            next.view.center = CGPointMake(next.view.center.x, next.view.center.y + 100);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [next.view removeFromSuperview];
            viewRevealed = NO;
        }];
    }
}
```

I usually do use container view controllers to do this kind of thing, but this works, and is very simple.

Comment: @Casper, this will probably cause problems if you want to do anything in the main view while the bottom view is showing (other than tap the button again to move out the bottom view).

Comment: Well you could still interact with the view, right? Just the top however many pixels would be off the top of the screen?

Comment: @Casper, I think it would depend on what you want to do in that view. I think it should work to interact with any UI elements, but what probably would cause problems, would be doing something that would transition to another view.

Comment: I am really close to finishing up this feature but I am stuck right now and could use a little help! Adding the subVC to the window allows us to interact with the view (which is great), but I can't get the view to rotate with the main view! Any recommendations? It stays on the view and is un-rotated...thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to want to use a UINavigationController and then push your new view controller once your button is tapped. So you would have your main UIViewController that would have your different options. When that button is tapped you would create an instance of the view controller and push that view controller onto the top of the stack. Your code might look something like this

```
-(IBAction)ViewControllerOneTapped:(id)sender
{   
    UIViewController *vcOne = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerOne" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcOne animated:YES];
}
```

Your final code is going to be much more complex than somebody can write out for you all the way but this is the general direction that you probably want to take.

Comment: This will not give the kind of transition the OP is looking for.